Eclipse WindowsBulder Editor .java Extension File Opening Problem Solution
The answer to windowBuilder in the .java file is not visible
Swing Defined .java File Mouse Right Click
Open With->Other
Select WindowsBuilder Editor in Editor Selection Window
Use this editor for all 'FileName.java' files Mark
Confirm with Ok Now it will open with WindowsBuilder Editor with Double Click.
I hope it helps
]

What is the question here? If you are trying to provide a simple tutorial on how to do something you must still ask a question and then write an answer

Eclipse WindowsBulder Editor .java Extension File Opening Problem Solution

Again, if you want to provide an answer to a problem you must write it as an answer. There is no problem writing a question and answering it yourself.

An information for those who experience this kind of problem.

Yes, but it must still be a question with a separate answer that you write. We do not accept questions which also contain the answer.
